# Information about ffmpeg command line options

Tags: ffmpeg

I have seen the use of `ffmpeg` in the command line, with the option `-strict -2`, or `-strict experimental`. I went to the [command line documentation of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), but I could not find information about this option.

Is there another site with more in-depth reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FFmpeg documentation [has recently](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html#news-30122012) been split up into multiple chapters, each describing components, including [separate docs for the codecs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html).

Here, there's a section about the `strict` option:

> `strict integer (decoding/encoding,audio,video)`
>
> Specify how strictly to follow the standards.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - `very`: strictly conform to a older more strict version of the spec or reference software
> - `strict`: strictly conform to all the things in the spec no matter what consequences
> - `normal`
> - `unofficial`: allow unofficial extensions
> - `experimental`: allow non standardized experimental things

Note that `integer` here just refers to the internal values… you should use `-strict experimental`, for example.

You can find a list of all these docs [on the documentation page](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html). Note that the online documentation is generated daily from the most recent FFmpeg code. Refer to your local documentation in the case of using an older version.

Comment: The doc split has been more annoying than I expected.

Comment: I don't *quite* understand it either. Especially new users won't know where to look now. Took me a couple of minutes to figure it out as well.

Comment: experimental is not an integer :-( is very 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @pike Yeah… the strings are translated to integers, internally. For example it's `-strict experimental`.

Answer (score 6):

As well as the online documentation, you can use `ffmpeg -h` (or `-h long` or `-h full` for more information).

It's not the question, but you can also get some information about specific encoders with `encoder=` (or decoders with `decoder=`) like so:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264
```

You can pipe this to `less`, in order to make it searchable.

```
ffmpeg -h full | less
```

Use `/string` to search for a string. In your case, `/strict`.

Answer (score 4):

Also not explained in the documentation are the integer values for "-strict": "-2" corresponds to "experimental", "0" for "normal", "2" for "very", etc.  Makes sense once you think about it, but a little weird at first (especially since "-2" looks like FFMPEG option syntax).  I just use the full name like "-strict experimental" but you will encounter both forms floating around the web.

Answer (score 4):

The  -strict experimental (or -strict -2) switch is now no longer needed in ffmpeg since 5th Dec 2015

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC for more information